# Help with calculating voltage using watts/ohms (batteries/coils)

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistance, watts, electricity

Okay, so I have no experience in EE (I do SE), so I don't know where to start. I apologize in advance this isn't the right place for this kind of question.

I bought a vaporizer with a small battery a while back, and the specs online say 3.7v 190mAh. Recently the battery died, but I have a much larger 3-7.5v 2000mAh Variable-Wattage battery that I want to use with the atomizer from the original battery. The resistance of the coil the current runs through in the atomizer is 2.44ohm, and I'm really trying not to blow out the atomizer or short it out with too much power, but using the interface I can only modify wattage, not voltage directly (if I'm correct in assuming it actually outputs 3.7v, or if that refers to something else I'm not aware of?)

TL;DR:
If I'm not mistaken:

```
3.7v -> 2.44ohm = 5.6w
3.8v = 2.44ohm <- 6.0w
```

That 0.1v shouldn't make a huge difference in the lifespan of the atomizer, right?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a variable voltage output on that "variable wattage battery"?

Comment: Yup, it has a digital voltmeter, watt meter, and ohm meter. The voltmeter just doesn't work

Comment: I don't think you can just assume that the resistance you are measuring will give you the correct wattage of that vaporizer. The original battery comes with 0,7 Wh. At the 5.6 W, it would be able to run around 7 minutes before the battery is drained. Is that value correct? If it is not, you have a different load than you expect. Use a constant voltage battery is my advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern e-cigarettes are usually vaped at between 10 W and 200 W. From your description it sounds like your particular atomizer is designed for the lower end of this range.

So try it at 10W. If that's too cool for you, increase the power by a couple of watts, and try again. Repeat until satisfied. No need to over-complicate it.

Pre-coiled atomizer heads have a limited lifespan anyway. They rarely last more than a few weeks with regular use. You should treat them as consumables, because that's what they are.

Comment: I ran it at 6 W for a couple days before it blew out on me. But yeah, i was expecting it to break soon anyway. I know you say no reason to over complicate it, but it all actually really interested me.

Comment: If you go to my site http://www.steam-engine.org and play around with the calculators, you'll probably learn a bit about how these things work. Remember to read the text below each calculator, I've tried to explain the central points in a somewhat succinct manner. The text below the "battery drain" calculator is particularly relevant to this question.